# During ajax post in mvc4 with huge data the system throws System.ArgumentException exception

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing ajax post to post the data from javascript in mvc4 but it fails with following exception

```
string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input
System.ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

I have already tried setting the configurations in web config but it is not working

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I also tried below link but nothing works:
 http://forums.asp.net/t/1751116.aspx?How+to+increase+maxJsonLength+for+JSON+POST+in+MVC3

```
var editorText = eval(htmlEditor).GetHtml();     
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "../Home/SaveExceptionLetter",
    data: JSON.stringify({ message: editorText }),
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function () {
    });
} });

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void SaveExceptionLetter(string message){
    //processing this message
}

string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input
System.ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

Comment: The web config setting that I have applied was  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

Comment: have a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config?rq=1

Answer (score 21):

Hi @usFarswan this is exactly what I came across  just half an hour ago , and the solution is http://forums.asp.net/t/1751116.aspx?How+to+increase+maxJsonLength+for+JSON+POST+in+MVC3

And you can implement it like that, in **global.asax** add the following lines pointed by ///*****.

```
namespace MyWebApp
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();


            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            DbHelper.getSessionFactory();

            ///// **********
             JsonValueProviderFactory jsonValueProviderFactory = null;

            foreach (var factory in ValueProviderFactories.Factories)
            {
                if (factory is JsonValueProviderFactory)
                {
                    jsonValueProviderFactory = factory as JsonValueProviderFactory;
                }
            }

            //remove the default JsonVAlueProviderFactory
            if (jsonValueProviderFactory != null) ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(jsonValueProviderFactory);

            //add the custom one
            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new CustomJsonValueProviderFactory());**
       /////*************
        }
    }




     ///********
    public sealed class CustomJsonValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
    {

        private static void AddToBackingStore(Dictionary<string, object> backingStore, string prefix, object value)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> d = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (d != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in d)
                {
                    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakePropertyKey(prefix, entry.Key), entry.Value);
                }
                return;
            }

            IList l = value as IList;
            if (l != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
                {
                    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakeArrayKey(prefix, i), l[i]);
                }
                return;
            }

            // primitive
            backingStore[prefix] = value;
        }

        private static object GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // not JSON request
                return null;
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
            string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
            {
                // no JSON data
                return null;
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; //increase MaxJsonLength.  This could be read in from the web.config if you prefer
            object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
            return jsonData;
        }

        public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (controllerContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
            }

            object jsonData = GetDeserializedObject(controllerContext);
            if (jsonData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Dictionary<string, object> backingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            AddToBackingStore(backingStore, String.Empty, jsonData);
            return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(backingStore, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        private static string MakeArrayKey(string prefix, int index)
        {
            return prefix + "[" + index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "]";
        }

        private static string MakePropertyKey(string prefix, string propertyName)
        {
            return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix)) ? propertyName : prefix + "." + propertyName;
        }
    }
   ///*************
}
```

Comment: That's the only solution on the web that worked for me. Thanks! :) Here is a shorter code for replacing the value provider factory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14591946/2173353 +1

Comment: Great soution, Thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This is the real solution. Thanks to @katmanco

Comment: Thank you so much this worked for me not the other web.config solutions.
Thanks again. you saved me. This error was driving me crazy and eating up a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

there is a another setting in web.config which you can try to increase:

```
<system.web>
  // the default request size is 4096 KB (4 MB) this will increase it to 100 MB
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" /> 
<system.web>
```

Comment: I have already done this request length setting But it is not working

Comment: I have edited the existing question please find the details above