# getting data more than 12000 rows and Ajax call problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

its a bit weird to me,i have a ajax call and a grid which shows the result,when i pick a date from yesterday to today it fine and even when i pick a date from 3days back to today the number of data is 7000 but still shows the data,the problem is when i pick a date from last week to today lets say 7 days,the number of data is around 14000 but ajax result shows me 1200!which is from yesterday to today!no idea hwy it happens

```
  function getData(dtFrom, dtTo) {

                $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("EventEntries", "TestController")",                     
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "dtfrom": dtFrom, "dtto": dtTo }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success:
                      function (result)                              
                       { tmp = result }
                });
                debugger;
                return tmp;

            }
```

Comment: Is anyone actually going to look at 14000 rows of data?  wouldn't you be better paginating it and returning it in smaller chunks?

Comment: @Pete thats right but this is what im toled,no way to skip it

Comment: Well, you will have to debug the query itself(along with column datatypes) and what you are sending from front end in `dtFrom` and `dtTo`.

Comment: @vivek_23 query side is fine,when i check it,i have 14000 rows

Comment: @mortezasol 14000 rows should be perfectly get-able in ajax response. Do you have any further logic that filters rows in your backend logic?

Comment: @vivek_23 not really i simply pass it  return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); like this

Comment: @vivek_23 I honestly think that 14000 rows would time out on the back end.

Comment: @vivek_23 how should i lift that limitation?

Comment: @bassxzero Makes sense, but OP says he could see 1200 rows. So I presume the ajax request got completed.

Comment: @mortezasol Does the request time out or does it get completed?

Comment: @vivek_23 I think the backend tries to write all the rows as output but it timesout after writing only 1200.

Comment: @bassxzero But OP says he could see 7000 rows with different dates.

Comment: @vivek_23 when i check in the browser network for up to 7000 data i get 200,but for more than that i get 500 error!

Comment: @mortezasol What is that 500 error? Check server logs for more info.

Comment: @vivek_23 XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @mortezasol No. a 5xx error is a server error. What errors do you see in your server logs?

Comment: @vivek_23 Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Comment: @mortezasol Not a ASP.NET dev but this shall help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881198/the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property

Comment: Show your "EventEntries" code.